# Use 2D array's column to get data from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have a JSON object:

```js
var bitShop = {
   "Potion": {
      "bits": 2000,
   },
};
```

I also have a 2D array (ignore column 2):

```js
var arr = [
   ["Potion", 1500]
]
```

I would like to reference the `bits` value using `arr[0][0]` (`arr[0][0]["bits"]`), but how I've tried solving it returns undefined. What is the correct syntax if I wanted to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is `bitShop[arr[0][0]].bits` what you want?

Comment: @ggorlen that's correct. Guess I forgot the `bitShop[` before the array